# Есть ли возможность получить адрес метки в C/С++?

Tags: c, c++

Нечто вроде такого кода:

```
void *address = адрес_метки(label);

label:

execute();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такая возможность есть в `gcc`. Это унарный оператор `&&`.

Создаем файл `label.c`:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    label:
    printf("label = %p\n", &&label);
}
```

Собираем, запускаем:

```
$ gcc label.c -o label && ./label
```

И получаем результат:

```
label = 0x80483cd
```